# Can't hide AppBar and BottomNavigation view with a behavior

Tags: android, layout

I found a problem trying to hide my app bar and bottom navigation view, they are both in a coordinator layout and i want to hide them when I scroll my recycler that is inside a my fragment view

[Main Activity Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkLTd.png)

I tryied to use every android material behaviour without any success

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.